# Iphone does not display background-image

Tags: html, css

I'm making a mobile website, when i display the page on my desktop an discrease the window size it works perfectly, but when I open the website on my iphone it does not display background images. 
Someone can help me?

http://i305098.iris.fhict.nl/mobile/

```
jsfiddle.net/8r2umLkj/
```

Comment: try removing `#main {
/* z-index: -999; */

}` from this

Comment: Does not solve the problem, thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

Try on another mobile device. It seems to be working fine for me.

Comment: Weird, what device u used?